# How do I use a headboard intended to mount on a wall onto a bed frame instead?

Tags: mounting, bedroom

I bought a headboard online without realising that it does not have legs. It's just an carved wooden plank that has holes on the back for it to be hung on a wall. I live in an apartment and I do not want to drill holes into the wall for it and I can't seem to find a bracket and bed frame that would help me attach it to the bed frame instead. Does anyone have any leads to which kind of bed frame/bracket I could use for this?

Comment: What bed frames **have** you found?  I don't know of any that lack head-and foot-board connectors as in the provided answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

([source](http://www.livingspaces.com/mattresses/metal-bed-frames))

You either screw *it*, or the legs you're going to add to it, to this (where it looks like a bracket on the end there).